# After uploading .apk to market, locally map v2 dont work

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I have uploaded .apk to market, and currently working on a new version v1.1 of app. But the maps in Eclipse doesn't show up. In other words uploaded version works but my current version in Eclipse don't work,

Key for Android apps (with certificates) API key is the same for both app, should I stick with the debug certificate fingerprint while working locally on my app, or should I make new API key every time I update my apk.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should have a key for debug and a key for publish. In short 2 keys no more, no less.

Comment: So signed API key is ONLY for release and mapview will ONLY show up when you install app from the market while DEBUG key is only for local development of app.

Comment: @Ecce_Homo what hinders you from having two working keys? You can register both development and publish key in the mapsv2 console.

Answer (score 0):

The debug Maps V2 key will only work for debug because it's signed with the debug keystore created by eclipse. While when publishing the app in the play store you will sign the apk with your own keystore wish you could create a GmapsV2 key with in the apis console.